# Which directories should be owned by root?

Tags: ubuntu

I Installed Ubuntu base and it boots to #, then I switch to root by doing `su -` . but I cannot modify any files as root, for instance, when I try to edit and save `/etc/hostname` , nano complains that it is a read-only filesystem.

I am guessing that during the installation I should have chowned the relevant directories under / like this:

```
chown -R root:root /bin /etc ...
```

Now there are a bunch of directories under / :

```
bin boot dev etc home lib lib32 lib64 libx32 lost+found media mnt opt proc
root run sbin srv sys tmp usr var
```

which ones should I set to be owned by root? should I also own the root dir like this:

```
chown root:root /
```

I also cannot modify any files under /home/user/ when I do `su user` ... should I do:

```
chown -R user:user /home/user/
```

Or should I just do this:

```
chown -R root:root /
chown -R user:user /home/user
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that you are misunderstanding what is going on:

Setting file permissions manually is strongly discouraged as far as it concerns the system directories, with a few exceptions (for example, if you create *new* configuration files in `/etc`, you should check and adjust their permissions afterwards). But I have never met a Linux or Unix distribution where you had to adjust the permissions on system directory trees before you could use it. You *really* should rely on your distribution regarding this, and you should not mess it up. It is *really really* crucial for system security. The one and only exception is if you build your own distribution from sources ...

Your *real* problem may be that the file system is damaged. Most systems regularly check the file system, e.g. when booting, **and mount it read-only if they see any problem.** The error message from `nano` you mentioned says exactly this:

It is not the permissions of an individual file `nano` complains about, but it says that the *file system as such* is read-only.

To resolve the situation, you have to find out the reason why the system mounts the affected file system read-only. As explained above, the most probable reason is that it has been damaged somehow. Another reason could be that *you* played around a little too much with your system :-) and made it mount the file system read-only. I don't know Ubuntu, but perhaps you can find a hint in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: if you look here you will see that setting up an Ubuntu Base system  is similar to LFS and  you are required to change the ownerships during the installation: http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter07/changingowner.html

Comment: I don't think so. I have had a quick look in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Base and disagree that Ubuntu Base is like LFS (from the link: "Ubuntu Base delivers a functional user-space environment [...]"). But even if it was, there obviously is something which makes your system mount the root file system read-only, so the most part of my answer should be correct anyway.

Comment: You are right, the file-system is not writable, https://ibb.co/t4G1m2c  What seems to be wrong here ? I am using Vmware, how can i make the file system writable ?

Comment: I believe that nobody can answer that question (this would be wild guessing). First, make sure that the VMware disk image on the host is not read-only for some reason. I don't know VMware, but it also might provide options to make disk images read-only. But most probably something went wrong with your Linux setup in the VM; there are zillions of reasons why Linux may mount the root FS read-only. I'd start with a Google search for the terms `Ubuntu base root file system read only` ...

Comment: Ok, when I was installing Ubuntu base, I chrooted and then mounted / and /boot..but then I exited without unmounting them...could this be why ?

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue because I don't know Ubuntu. There (and in every other Linux distribution) must be a place (config file) where the system is told which file systems to mount during boot, and how to mount them. This is the place I would check first. Ubuntu probably has documentation about that subject (I really don't know).

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas That will not help the OP because his root file system is read-only. `sudo` won't change that ...